# Solr delivering zero results when value list reaches certain size

Tags: solr

I am querying a Solr (4.5) with a query like

```
(ean:(boh OR dqn OR irc OR kjv OR jwn OR opf) AND aggregatorId:0)
```

This works and delivers six results. But if I make the size of the list of values for ean very big (about 10.000 values, including the ones formerly found), the server delivers a valid answer containing 0 documents. I have configured the server to allow this number of values in solrconfig.xml:

```xml
<query>
     <maxBooleanClauses>65536</maxBooleanClauses>
     <filterCache
           class="solr.FastLRUCache"
           size="512"
           initialSize="512"
           autowarmCount="0"/>

     <queryResultCache
           class="solr.LRUCache"
           size="512"
           initialSize="512"
           autowarmCount="0"/>

     <documentCache
           class="solr.LRUCache"
           size="512"
           initialSize="512"
           autowarmCount="0"/>

     <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
     <queryResultWindowSize>50</queryResultWindowSize>
     <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
     <HashDocSet maxSize="2048" loadFactor="0.75"/>
     <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
     <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>
</query>
```

How come I don't get any result when enlarging the list of values for ean?

There is no error message in the Solr log, and the answer is valid (but wrong). When I set the maxBooleanClauses to e.g. 2048, I expectedly get an 400 error result with the too many boolean clauses error in the Solr log.

UPDATE:
I have experimented a bit with the sizes; up to 9055 elements in the list it still works; for 9056 it doesn't any more.

I have tried upgrading to Solr 4.8; same phenomenon still.

Making the contents of the ean field longer or shorter has also no effect on the behaviour (I have thought of a problem with queries above 64k size, e.g. with any cache or buffer, but nope).

Comment: Can you see any exception or an error in the solr server logs?

Comment: As I stated, no error or exception neither. Everything seems fine, except that no result is found. I also trace the query in an additional log; it is completely delivered.